# This field cannot be blank

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I want to add image in Django admin, but when I chose img, fill all fields and click on Save, I saw next message 'This field cannot be blank.' near img field. In django console all is good, I havent any bugs(on local server all works).

What did I do wrong?

Comment: you are on production?

Comment: yes, I am on production server

Comment: do you have a media/statick url/ static files handler?

Comment: MEDIA_ROOT = 'static/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

Comment: and the handlers

Comment: in urls.py `urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

Comment: + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: did it work now

Comment: No, it is not. I check all code.

Comment: who is your hoster, pythonanywhere/AWS...

Comment: Do you think my hoster can restrict uploading?

Comment: No, do you have a bash console? in the prduction env

Comment: No, in console wrote that all is good (200)